# Why event is not being consumed?

Tags: javascript, events, click

I have a web page with a menu+submenus with a bunch of `<a>` anchors. When any of these anchors is clicked, a page is opened in an `iframe`. It works fine, except that in mobile browsers the submenu remains opened even after clicking it, so the event is not 'consumed'. Why?

I do this with the following. First, I set the `onclick` function:

```
var anchors = MyMethodGetElementByClassName('loadt');
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
 anchors[i].onclick = function(e) {
  loadthis(e,this.href);
 }
}
```

In the method `loadthis`, I do this:

```
function loadthis(e,pg)
 var evt = e || window.event;
 if (evt != 88 && evt !== "null") {
  evt.preventDefault();
 }
 frame.src = pg;
 $('html').trigger('click');
 return false;
}
```

The last two lines of `loadthis` are to try to consume the event by triggering a click in the document and by returning false. Yet, the submenus remain opened.

Take a look [here](http://luis.impa.br) in a smartphone (click, say, in "Software > Ave").

Comment: Not related to the question, maybe invest in changing the font from Comic Sans..

Comment: I'm curious: It *looks* like you're using jQuery from that `$('html').trigger('click");` line. If so, why aren't you using it for finding the elements, hooking up the handler, and normalizing event handling across browsers?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I am not familiar with JQuery, my code almost doesn't use it. I don't know about this 'normalization'...?

Comment: @Stefan: I didn't understand your comment about Comic Sans font. I "invested" in implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *handler* isn't returning any value. The function it calls (`loadthis`) is, but it isn't. *(But keep reading.)*

To make your *handler* return a value, return the result of calling `loadthis`:

```
var anchors = MyMethodGetElementByClassName('loadt');
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
 anchors[i].onclick = function(e) {
  return loadthis(e,this.href);
//^^^^^^^
 }
}
```

Also, you appear to be supporting older browsers. If so, you'll need to put a guard on your `preventDefault` call (although you don't actually need it; the way you're hooking up the event, `return false` is sufficient; [details in this minor post on my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html)). E.g.:

```
function loadthis(e,pg)
 var evt = e || window.event;
 if (evt != 88 && evt !== "null" && evt.preventDefault) {
// -----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  evt.preventDefault();
 }
 frame.src = pg;
 $('html').trigger('click');
 return false;
}
```

Finally: `evt` will always be `!= 88` and will always be `!== "null"`, so you could and probably should remove those.

**However**, you appear to be using jQuery, from that `$('html').trigger('click');` line. If so, this can all be markedly simplified:

```
$(".loadt").on("click", function() {
    $('html').trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

...since the `evt != 88 && evt !== "null"` would always be true anyway... That will also stop propagation (instead of just preventing the default), which may help.

Comment: Added the `return` and the `evt.preventDefault`, but problem persists (you can check the page). (The 88 thing is because the method is longer, I just showed the relevant parts, yet forgot to remove the 88. My bad).

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: It may well be that you need to stop propagation as well as preventing the default, see the jQuery bit at the end of the answer.

Comment: You meant to add `loadthis` into your JQuery code, too, right? And, sorry, but what does it mean to "prevent propagation"?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: No, that jQuery code at the end does what the `loadthis` function in the question did, but in a cross-browser compatible way. "Stop propagation" means stopping the event from bubbling. More: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow

Comment: It worked, but with this JQuery instead (need to pass the event to cancel the default, and to execute the main `loadthing` function): `$(".loadt").on("click", function(e) { $('html').trigger('click'); return loadthis(e,this.href); });`
I will take a look on the propagation thing. Thanks!